# Get line after matching pattern > 0 in linux

Tags: logging, search, awk, grep, command-line-interface

I have this log, and I want to print the lines with the "finished" status for the Jobs where "QTY REGS > 0" without using a script.

```
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:00,001 JOB: 0970b711] starting
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:01,001 JOB: 0970b711] adding records
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:02,001 JOB: 0970b711] registered
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:03,001 JOB: 0970b711] QTY REGS: 3 processing
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:03,001 JOB: 32970g233] debug started
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:04,001 JOB: 0970b711] finished
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:05,001 JOB: 10d0g655] starting
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:06,001 JOB: 10d0g655] QTY REGS: 0 processing
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:07,001 JOB: 10d0g655] finished
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:08,001 JOB: 0870a711] starting
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:09,001 JOB: 0870a711] QTY REGS: 1 processing
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:10,001 JOB: 0870a711] retry
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:11,001 JOB: 0870a711] connect error
INFO  2021-01-19 02:00:12,001 JOB: 0870a711] finished
```

I would like to return for

```
INFO 2021-01-19 02:00:03,001 JOB: 0970b711] QTY REGS: 3 processing
INFO 2021-01-19 02:00:09,001 JOB: 0870a711] QTY REGS: 1 processing
```

That are the records where **QTY REGS > 0** the lines with the same job number but that have "finished" as description

```
INFO 2021-01-19 02:00:04,001 JOB: 0970b711] finished
INFO 2021-01-19 02:00:12,001 JOB: 0870a711] finished
```

Comment: See [ask], [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting then try again. [I see](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12607387/luis) you've been a member for over a year and asked 5 previous questions though so you should really know that by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use an array:

```
awk '$6=="QTY" && $8>0{a[$5]=1}; $6=="finished" && a[$5]==1{print}' file
```

Output:

```
INFO 2021-01-19 02:00:04,001 JOB: 0970b711] finished
INFO 2021-01-19 02:00:12,001 JOB: 0870a711] finished
```

`{print}` can also be omitted.